# Adding multiple columns in pyspark dataframe using a loop

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I need to add a number of columns (4000) into the data frame in pyspark. I am using the `withColumn` function, but getting assertion error.

```
df3 = df2.withColumn("['ftr' + str(i) for i in range(0, 4000)]", [expr('ftr[' + str(x) + ']') for x in range(0, 4000)])
```

[image: Eror]

Not sure what is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to do something like this:

```
df2 = df3
for i in range(0, 4000):
  df2 = df2.withColumn(f"ftr{i}", lit(f"frt{i}"))
```

Comment: I dont think. it will. it will just add one field-i.e. last one

-- ftr3999: string (nullable = false)

Comment: @renjith has you actually tried to run it?. The solutions will add all columns. Note that inside the loop I am using df2 = df2.witthColumn and not df3 = df2.withColumn

Comment: Yes i ran it. Output when i do printschema is this
root
 |-- hashval: string (nullable = true)
 |-- dec_spec_str: string (nullable = false)
 |-- dec_spec  array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: double (containsNull = true)
 |-- ftr3999: string (nullable = false)

Comment: it works. not sure. why it did not work when i tried first

Comment: @renjith How did this looping worked for you. It's not working for me as well.

Answer (score 10):

We can use `.select()` instead of `.withColumn()` to use a list as input to create a similar result as chaining multiple `.withColumn()`'s. The `["*"]` is used to select also every existing column in the dataframe.

`import pyspark.sql.functions as F`

df2:

```
+---+
|age|
+---+
| 10|
| 11|
| 13|
+---+
```

`df3 = df2.select(["*"] + [F.lit(f"{x}").alias(f"ftr{x}") for x in range(0,10)])`

Results in:

```
+---+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|age|ftr0|ftr1|ftr2|ftr3|ftr4|ftr5|ftr6|ftr7|ftr8|ftr9|
+---+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| 10|   0|   1|   2|   3|   4|   5|   6|   7|   8|   9|
| 11|   0|   1|   2|   3|   4|   5|   6|   7|   8|   9|
| 13|   0|   1|   2|   3|   4|   5|   6|   7|   8|   9|
+---+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

Comment: This is a much more efficient way to do it compared to calling withColumn in a loop!